# Score partial match in title field greater than exact match in description field of the product

Tags: solr

I need to score partial match in the title field higher than exact match in the description field. Actually I need to sort my solr result based on the following five conditions

1. First: results with a whole word match on the first or second word in the NAME go on top.
2. Then: results with a whole word match elsewhere in the NAME.
3. Then: results with a partial word match anywhere in the NAME.
4. Then: results with a whole word match in the INFOTEXT.
5. Finally: results with a partial word match in the INFOTEXT.

For this I have added four fields like `titleExact`, `titlePartial`, `descriptionExact`, `DescriptionPartial` and boosted `titleExact` score higher than all others.

But I am not getting result as expected.

Following are the field definitions for exact and partial field

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general_partial" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" delimiter="$" encoder="float"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="3"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" delimiter="$" encoder="float"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Comment: Didn't you add this question a short time ago? What has changed? What happened with the old question? Please add examples of the results you are getting from your input and what you expected as well.

Comment: Please do share the sample data as well

Comment: Actually the question is same just added the definition of the field which I used

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti....data for example I have documents as below

Lucene Solr--doc1
Lucene solr is wonderful--doc2
Welcome back to lucene--doc3
Example lucene solr--doc4

When I am searching with word lucene I need result in following order
doc1 doc2 doc4 doc3 but now I am getting doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4